# Getting problem the resource has been modified?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

I am getting problem the "Resource has been modified at the time of syncing the App".

3 days before my App was installed successfully but now its been getting Resource modified problem and unable to found the reason why this is happening so.
I have done R&D on it but still not getting the needful solution on it.
If you would suggest me the Reasons why this problem occurs, that would be helpful in my R&D process.

So , Please help me out with this problem .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the deployment issue and clean the built and run the program,hope this will be useful,

shift button+control button+k button to clean